# SSRS 2008 - Return Next Available Record Based On Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Given the following dataset in the temporary table #RawAlarms:

[image: Dataset]
I need to return the first instance of each AlarmState='UNACK_ALM', inline with the very next instance of the AlarmState 'ACK_ALM' OR 'ACK_RTN' but **NOT BOTH**.

The query I am running looks like:

```
SELECT RA1.TagName, RA1.DateTime, RA1.Description, RA2.Description, MIN(RA2.DateTime) as AckDT
FROM #RawAlarms RA1
INNER JOIN #RawAlarms RA2 ON RA1.TagName = RA2.TagName AND RA2.DateTime > RA1.DateTime 
    AND RA1.LotStartDT = RA2.LotStartDT and RA1.LotEndDT = RA2.LotEndDT
WHERE RA1.AlarmState = 'UNACK_ALM' AND RA2.AlarmState IN('ACK_RTN','ACK_ALM')
GROUP BY RA1.TagName, RA1.DateTime, RA1.Description, RA2.Description
ORDER BY RA1.TagName, RA1.DateTime
```

These are the results I'm getting; highlighted in Red are an example of the results I need:
[image: DataResults]
HELP

Comment: Ended up NULLing out the Description fields, INSERT INTOing the results to an additional temporary table, then UPDATEing that Table with the Description fields.  Seems messy but works.  Still open to something more elegant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [APPLY operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) can help here:

```
SELECT RA1.TagName, RA1.DateTime, RA1.Description, NextAlarmState.Description, NextAlarmState.DateTime AS AckDT
FROM #RawAlarms RA1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 RA2.Description, RA2.DateTime
                 FROM #RawAlarms RA2
                 WHERE RA2.LotStartDT = RA1.LotStartDT 
                     AND RA2.LotEndDT = RA1.LotEndDT
                     AND RA2.DateTime > RA1.DateTime
                     AND RA2.AlarmState IN ('ACK_RTN', 'ACK_ALM')
                 ORDER BY RA2.DateTime) AS NextAlarmState
WHERE RA1.AlarmState = 'UNACK_ALM'
ORDER BY RA1.TagName, RA1.DateTime
```

Comment: Revisited this issue as a learning experience, and the above seems to work!  Interesting; I had not thought to use CROSS APPLY before.  I'll have to look at that one!